# How should I pay RHEL licences with RHEL based container

Tags: docker, openshift, rhel

I am evaluating Openshift Container Platform for my company.

We will install it on top of RHEL.

Should I pay a licence for RHEL for each container that is built on tp of RHEL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OpenShift Container Platform nodes will have a RHEL subscription. When you build a container in OpenShift, and it happens on one of these RHEL machines, the subscription info will be available to the build, so that you can do things that you'd need a subscription for, such as `yum install`, etc.

Running RHEL-based containers on OpenShift is also covered by the subscription on the OpenShift Container Platform node machines.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you don't need to. Or this kind of stuff is included in the Openshift license. The best way to get the proper answer would be to ask your RedHat commercial.

I'm using RHEL containers to test our products as part of our CI without paying a license, nothing technically blocking.